# How to override translation CSV for Magento_Review Module?

Tags: magento2

I want to change translation in Magento_Review module.

Created same directory structure on my theme. But it's not working.

```
app/design/frontend/custom/theme/Magento_Review/i18n/en_US.csv

"Add Your Review","Write Your Review"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the changes in the theme's `i18n` directory. i.e,

```
app/design/frontend/custom/theme/i18n/en_US.csv

"Add Your Review","Write Your Review"
```

Comment: It's not working. And also I don't want to create generic translation file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only place you can change this. see the official documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/theme_dictionary.html

Comment: If you are in production mode, you need to flush the cache and flush the browser cache too.

Answer (score -1):

You have to just override en_US.csv file into your theme i18n folder.

app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv